# Django filter some amount of records

Tags: sql, django

I would like to filter first 20 records out of a Model, is there a way to do it in Django. Or should I be using raw SQL?

Comment: Could you post the model?  Also how are you going to sort the records?  By Date Created?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
first_twenty = MyModel.objects.filter.order_by('id')[:20]
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much. I just realised i need the rest of the model objects than the 20. Any idea how i can do that?

Comment: all_objects = MyModel.objects.all()